# How do I implement VarArgs using inheritance?

Tags: java

I am given a class PolyShape represents polygons by their number of sides and an array that contains their side lengths and I have to extend it into a class called quadrilateral that represents a polygon with 4 sides. I am unsure of how to approach this as. I started the program but could someone help me explain what I am supposed to include in terms of arrays and how I should use VarArgs in this case?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PolyShape {
private int numSides;
private int[] sideLengths;

public PolyShape(int ... sideLengths) {
    this.sideLengths = sideLengths;
    this.numSides = sideLengths.length;
}

public int getNumSides() {
    return numSides;
}
public int[] getSideLengths() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(sideLengths, sideLengths.length);
}
public int getPerimeter() {
    int perim = 0;
    for(int n : sideLengths)
        perim += n;
    return perim;
}
public String toString() {
    String s = "I am a shape with " + numSides + " sides of length: ";
    for(int length : sideLengths) 
        s += length + " ";
    s += "\nI am a polygon.";
    return s;
}
}
```

Quadrilateral class:

```
public class Quadrilateral extends PolyShape {

private final int POLYGON_SIDES = 4;

public Quadrilateral(int ... sideLengths) {
    super(sideLengths);
}

public String toString() {
    String parentString = super.toString();
    parentString += "\nI am a Quadrilateral.";
    return parentString;
}
}
```

Comment: What you've done looks fine.  I think maybe what you were supposed to do was write the `Quadrilateral` constructor in such a way that it had to take four arguments, instead of a vararg.  This could look something like `public Quadrilateral(int side1, int side2, int side3, int side4) { super(side1, side2, side3, side4); }`

Comment: You're more likely to get any other useful feedback (and I can definitely think of some) from http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you! does this mean that there is no use for my constant? Would it be safe just to get rid of it? And I didn't have to include extra getters and setters?

Comment: I'd say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You child class is Quadrilateral and it has 4 sides so you don't need to create constructor with vararg method argument. just pass 4 sides inside constructor. Passing those 4 sides to parent constructors will definitely call parent constructor with vararg argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Quadrilateral extends PolyShape {
  public Quadrilateral(int side1, int side2, int side3, int side4) {
      super(side1, side2, side3, side4);
  }    
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.